# How to add a MVC Account controller to WebApi project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to understand the concept of one asp.net. I did the entire exercise [here.](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api)
Its easy.

Now trying to understand further, I created a new Asp.Net project and selected Web API template as follows. So we see that MVC and Web API check boxes are selected.

[image: New Web Api project template in VS 2013]

If I observe the project The AccountController is an ApiController and so the views folder does not have any Account and Manage folders as expected.

[image: Account controller for web api]

**Now my question is how do I add an Mvc Account controller to the above project?** I very well know that if I select MVC in the new project dialog as follows I can get that.

[image: New MVC project template in VS 2013]

What I want is to add is an MVC account controller along with the views exactly like the following in the Web api project show earlier.

[image: Account Controller for MVC]

This should be very easy I guess. So could someone please describe some steps? Like for example, which model and context we need to select on add scaffold and then Add Controller dialogs?

[image: Add Scaffold dialog]
[image: Add Controller dialog after Scaffold dialog]

In other words **I want to understand looking at a controller say AccountController be it Api or Mvc, how do I understand what is the model class and Data context associated with it**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plenty of scafold templates that exists are very useful to have an application running. Even you can create a new WepApplication project and add the [Nuget package AspNet.Identity Sample](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples), wich has a lot of features.

However for your project, I recommend you to start with and Empty Web Api project and then start adding only the stuff that you need. This way you will understand better how your Wep Api works with AspNet Identity (Account Management, External Login Providers like Google or Facebook, ...).

This [Step by Step tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) (and the next series) will guide you in implementing and understanding the Web Api and AspNet Identity starting from an Empty Web Api project.

Hope this helps.